# Export by Blend4Web

Tags: blend4web

I'm a beginner of "Blend4Web". So I have a question about the export. I baked some skeletal animation and exported it as a html-file. Of course, I edited the bake data by the NLA Editor before export it. 
But any animation data wasn't included in the result. I refer to the URL below. Is there a shortage in the description of this article?

https://www.blend4web.com/en/article/36/

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to judge without the .blend file. Maybe the "NLA" option under Scene tab is turned off? Try enabling it.

You can also ask it on B4W forums and attach the file there.

Here's [Animation Baking section](https://www.blend4web.com/doc/en/animation.html?#skinning-and-skeletal-animation) in B4W documentation - look through it, maybe you'll find what's wrong :)

Comment: Hi PKotov,Thanks for your advice, I was able to solve the problem.
Thank you so much! ;-)